# The for loop isn't entered even if the initial requirement is true

Tags: c++, for-loop, arduino-c++

I have the following function with a for loop inside it. The code is run on an Arduino and the `Serial.print` function shows that the function is entered correctly with the correct input value. But the for loop isn't entered. Does anyone have an idea why?

```
void openvalveCold(int steps){
    Serial.println(steps);

    // Steps is confimed to be 200. 
    digitalWrite(sleep1,HIGH);

    for (antalsteg = 0; antalsteg == steps; antalsteg++)
    {  
        Serial.println("2");  

        //digitalWrite(dir1,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(stepp1,HIGH);

        delay(25);
        digitalWrite(stepp1,LOW);
        delay(25);
        Serial.println(antalsteg);

        nr_of_steps_cold++;
    }
}

void loop{
    // calling on function
    openvalveCold(200);
}
```

Comment: The loop will happen whenever `antalsteg == steps`. Which is  never.

Comment: If `steps` is 200, then the condition `antalsteg == steps`  will be false (as `antalseg` is set to 0....)

Comment: Because the initial requirement is not true.

Answer (score 4):

A for loop is usually constructed like this:

```
for(init counter; condition; increase counter)
```

You have made the (false) assumption that it loops *until* the condition is true. That's wrong. It loops *while* it is true. Change to:

```
for (antalsteg = 0; antalsteg < steps; antalsteg++)
```

Comment: Very good reply.  You didn't just answer WHAT was wrong (`antalsteg == steps`), but you explained WHY it was wrong ... and HOW to fix it.

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks. Only wish I was a tiny bit faster. :)

Answer (score 3):

The loop isn't entered because the condition is false when the loop starts:

```
for (antalsteg = 0; antalsteg == steps; antalsteg++)
```

When the conditional of the loop is first evaluated, `antalsteg` is 0 and `steps` is 200.  So `antalsteg == steps` evaluated to `0 == 200` which is false.  So the loop is never entered.